# Specific material icon is not showing offline

Tags: angular-material, icons, offline

My angular application is hosted on a server with no internet connection, because of that, I removed the following code from my *index.html*:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">`

And downloaded them via npm: `npm install material-design-icons --save`

And added them like this in my *idex.html* :
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css">`

Everything seems fine, mostly of the icons work except for this one:
[image]

No matter if I use it like this:

```
<span class="material-icons">
  read_more
</span>
```

or this

```
<mat-icon
  read_more
</mat-icon>
```

or even as the character code, since I thought it has something todo with ligatures (I took the code from here https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.codepoints)

```
<mat-icon>
  &#xef6d;
</mat-icon>
```

It does work if  I use `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">` in my *index.html* and have an internet connection, but I need to find a way for it to work without an internet connection.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using "fontface": https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource

I installed int by using `npm install @fontsource/material-icons`, this adds the following folder:

[image]

I replaced added in my main style file with the following:

```
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

And in my main styles file (I use scss) I added the following:

`@import "~@fontsource/material-icons/index.css";`

That did the trick for me. I also were able to use the icon without the code:

```
<mat-icon>read_more</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try to add it in angular.json rather than index.html. Also, check if that icon is available in the version you have downloaded. Try to downgrade the package and run the npm install command.

Comment: Adding it to the angular.json didn't help. I tried to find out if the icon is availabe here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons/v/3.0.0. But couldn't find it. Where can I check if the icon is part of the version?

Comment: I found some links. See if you could find what you want 1. https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-material-icons-list-mat-icon-list/ and https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/ and http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/. In the last link you could download the repo code to see all the icons.